# HTML5 media 'progress' event is not fired in android chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, html5-video

I am trying to bind HTML5 video's progress event. It works fine on desktop chrome. But same event is not getting triggered on android chrome 42. Here is what I am trying to do :

```
$('video').bind('progress', function(e) { console.log("Progress event..");});
```

Am I missing something or Is there any work around to make it work on android mobile chrome?

Thanks.

Comment: If the video is already cached, progress event does not fire on chrome. BTW, you are not confusing progress with timeupdate right? Because i had confused once.

Comment: I dont to want to listen on download progress. Its html5 media's progress event which is fired when media is pushed to sourcebuffer and is available within its timeranges.